# Regarding Angular 5 Automation using Protractor with C#

Tags: c#, protractor

This is with regards to Angular 5 Automation with Protractor using c#

Currently my application is developed based on Angular5 with Primeng UI components and kendo grid. Please find the following queries:

a) Can protractor be used to Automate angular 5 application ?

b) When I try to inspect, there are no ng-model, ng-reflect, ng-binding, ng-repeat etc.. available ? Should I discuss with development team to add these locators for Angular 5 or any other locators are available ?

c) Can I use the nuget package protractor in visual studio and start writing code in c#.Does that protractor nuget package support angular 5 Automation ? In our company I am not supposed to use JavaScript or typescript. How feasible it is to write in c# using the protractor package ?

d) Do you have any guideline that a developer should follow in Angular 5 development to cater E2e testing using protractor.net. Like ex for a input box what angular attribute to be added ?
For a drop down ? For a grid what angular attribute to be added ?

e) There are two types of build prod build and dev build. Actually we are supposed to test in prod build but unable to find any angular components in prod build, as the webpack tool coverts all the angular components to javascript  . In this case where there are no angular components in prod build. How to Automate ?

Please help me with these queries and in case you have any solution for protractor.net please share.

Answer (score 0):

a) Can protractor be used to Automate angular 5 application ?

Yes it can be used to automate angular 5 appl's

b) When I try to inspect, there are no ng-model, ng-reflect, ng-binding, ng-repeat etc.. available ?

Above ng's can be present in angular 1 version (angular js), you dont bother about that, But still you can use Id, Xpath, className, model, buttonText.

C) Can I use the nuget package protractor in visual studio and start writing code in c#.Does that protractor nuget package support angular 5 Automation ? In our company I am not supposed to use JavaScript or typescript. How feasible it is to write in c# using the protractor package ?

Yes you can use protractor nuget package support angular 5 Automation, You need to install,

Install-Package Protractor -Version ----, Protractor C # is not widely used like Protractor-js and Protractor-ts Combo. But still it has good support with C#.